# How to maintain version of Drools Decision table

Tags: java, jboss, drools

Here is my scenario  I am using drools for storing the rules mainly decision tables not I have a scenario where I want to create version of my knowledge. and depending on certain param want to use the knowledge.

today is my base engine when I am deciding the rules and everything. tomorrow if it changes than it should affect only the new user and old user should be able to use the older rules and if it changes again than we have three sets of user and three sets of rules.

I could see that I can maintain different Excel file and load them all and keep adding them once I get some changes in the rule.

In the same file I could have a date or some flag by that I could decide which rule has to be used.

but none of this seems to be looks like a standard drools solution to me. any thoughts or suggestions

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken Drools Guvnor offers an option to publish different versions of your rule set. In a similar fashion as companies can publish different versions of Web Services.

Please comment back on this as I'm also interested whether I'm correct or not and it'll work in such a manner :)